# Animated Panel in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, button, panel

I am trying to add a panel when a button click. My code is below and I did it. But now I am trying to put on my panel other buttons etc and when you click the first button and the panel slide in there aren't any of my new buttons.

```
//Constants
    const int AW_SLIDE = 0X40000;
    const int AW_HOR_POSITIVE = 0X1;
    const int AW_HOR_NEGATIVE = 0X2;
    const int AW_BLEND = 0X80000;

        [DllImport("user32")]
        
        static extern bool AnimateWindow(IntPtr hwnd, int time, int flags);
        photosflag=0;
           
 private void photosbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (photosflag == 0)
            {
                object O = Controller.Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("photospressed");
                photosbutton.Image = (System.Drawing.Image)O;
                photosflag = 1;
                int ylocation = photosbutton.Location.Y;
                //Set the Location
                photospanel.Location = new Point(101, ylocation);

                //Animate form
                AnimateWindow(photospanel.Handle, 500, AW_SLIDE | AW_HOR_POSITIVE);
                
                
            }
            else
            {
                object O = Controller.Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("photos");
                photosbutton.Image = (System.Drawing.Image)O;
                photosflag = 0;
                photospanel.Visible = false;

            }
           
           
        }
```

In the photos panel, I have three picture boxes. But when the panel shows up (slide-in) the picture boxes there aren't exist.

Comment: I'm not following you entirely - are you saying that the panel has already been created in the designer, but just isn't visible until you click the button?  If so, are you sure the other controls are actually contained in the panel? - if you move the panel in the designer, do the sub-controls move with it?

Comment: Yes. The sub-controls move with panel. When i start the application the panel visible is false... When you click a button the panel is visible but the sub-controls aren't visible.(with animated panel). If i just write panel.Visible= true without animated it shows me the sub-controls

Comment: Interesting.  I don't really know anything about the AnimateWindow api, but it doesn't seem to play very nice with WinForms.  Is your animation just sliding it into position?  If so, couldn't you write your own .NET code to do this?  You could use a timer to incrementally move it into position - right?

Comment: My code is in my question on top. If you write this code inside a simple form you will see what is my animation. It's just a simple sliding. Create a button (100X100) at the top left corner and a panel next to your button(make it unvisible). When you click the button the panel slide in left to right. But if you create button inside this panel you will not see them. Try it and help me. (Happy New Year)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay - here is a really simple example that doesn't depend on the AnimateWindow API:

Add a timer control to your form.  On mine, I set the interval to 10 (milliseconds).  You can play with this value to smooth out the animation as necessary

I have the button and panel (not visible) on the form

I declared the following private members on the form - they are the start X position of the panel, the end position, and the number of pixels to move per increment - again, tweak to affect speed/smoothness/etc

```
private int _startLeft = -200;  // start position of the panel
private int _endLeft = 10;      // end position of the panel
private int _stepSize = 10;     // pixels to move
```

Then on the button click, I enable the timer:

```
animationTimer.Enabled = true;
```

Finally, the code in the timer tick event makes the panel visible, moves it into place, and disables itself when done:

```
private void animationTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // if just starting, move to start location and make visible
    if (!photosPanel.Visible)
    {
        photosPanel.Left = _startLeft;
        photosPanel.Visible = true;
    }

    // incrementally move
    photosPanel.Left += _stepSize;
    // make sure we didn't over shoot
    if (photosPanel.Left > _endLeft) photosPanel.Left = _endLeft;

    // have we arrived?
    if (photosPanel.Left == _endLeft)
    {
        animationTimer.Enabled = false;
    }            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but there’s an easy fix for the photos not showing. The panel is originally set to visible = false, and because AnimateWindow doesn't actually show the full control, so make sure you set control.Visible = true after calling AnimateWindow.
so after the code line:

```
//Animate form

AnimateWindow(photospanel.Handle, 500, AW_SLIDE | AW_HOR_POSITIVE);

// just add this:

photopanel.Visible = true;

// or in one line

Photopanel.Visible = AnimateWindow(photospanel.Handle, 500, AW_SLIDE | AW_HOR_POSITIVE);
```